# Prove that $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$ satisfies the axioms of a category and that the product and coproduct of a finite family of objects exist in it

Tags: category-theory

Lets define a category $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$ from $\mathbb Z^+$ and the division relationship like this:

- The objects of $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$ are the elements of $\mathbb Z^+$
- If $a,b \in $$\mathbb Z^+$, i.e, $a,b$ are positive integers, we define the following morphism:

$Hom_{X_{\mathbb Z^+}}(a,b)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \{(a,b)\} &   if  & a|b\\
             \\ \emptyset &  if & a\nmid b \\
                    \end{array}
   \right.$

> a)Verify that with these definitions, $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$ satisfies the axioms of a category

> b)Prove that the product and coproduct of any finite family of objects $\{a_1,....a_n\} $ exist in $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$.

I know that in the positive integers, the relationship of division is an order relationship, i.e, it is refelexive, transitive and antisymmetric. I also know that the axioms of the categories are:

1. Associativity: If $f:A\rightarrow B, g: B\rightarrow C, h: C\rightarrow D$ are morphisms of the class $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$, then $h\circ(g\circ f)= (h \circ g)\circ f$
2. Identity: For each object $B$ of $X_{\mathbb Z^+}$ there exists a morphism $1_B:B\rightarrow B$ such that for any $f:A\rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow C,$ $1_B\circ f=f$ and $g\circ1_B=g$

Can I get some help, please?

Comment: Figure out when composition can happen, and what the answer will be in the situation. That will make everything immediate.

Comment: Those category axioms are basically right, but as @ArturoMagidin points out, you skipped over the operation of composing two morphisms. Try some examples: when should the composition exist, and what is it? Then try (1) and (2). (Technically, by the way, the relation of divisibility ($|$) is not an order but a _partial order_.)